# Export/Import Packages for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Yesterday I have installed Xamarin for Visual Studio on a Laptop with my internet connection from home. Today I want to work with this installed version of Xamarin but my IDE tells me that I have to update my packages in order to have full access to things like the AXML-Designer. The bad news are that I have no possibility to access the given internet with laptop but only with a second PC.

So my question is if it is possible to download and install the packages on a PC and then export these packages to another PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, all you need is Visual Studio 2015 Update 2:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Comment: I don't need to install the packages? Just the Update?

Comment: @Snickbrack If you are working with Visual Studio 2015 and have already installed it but do not have latest version, then you can just install the update I linked to. If you are not working with Visual Studio 2015 then what IDE are you using and what specific error message are you getting?